# How to unset relation in 'find'?

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I have content type "Novel" and have relation with "Tag" and "Genre", I want to only show "Tag" and "Genre" in 'findOne' but not in 'find'. using m.unset in models/Novels.js only working if the data is not relation. how can I un-populate this Tag in 'find'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with that by updating the **find** function of the **Novel** API.

Here is the documentation to update the controller function https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/controllers.html

You will have to copy and past the **find** function code.

And replace `return strapi.services.product.find(ctx.query);` by `return strapi.services.product.find(ctx.query, []);`

We add an empty array because the second argument is here to specify data you want to populate. By passing an empty array you say to not populate data.